# How to optimize redundant selectors with gulp-cssnano (or else)

Tags: css, node.js, gulp, minify

[`gulp-minify-css` says quite cleary, that is has been deprecated in favor of [gulp-cssnano](https://github.com/ben-eb/gulp-cssnano).]

I am quite happy with thi css minification of cssnano, except for two things..

- identical selectors with no interference otherwise do not get merged, i.e. `body, html` or `h1, h2, h3`  in the sample below
- identical media query-‘brackets’ are not joined into one big query bracket, i.e. `@media only screen and (max-width:500px)`
- even certain overrulings even on the very same selectors and precedence are not pruned (i.e. color:orange over green for `h1,h2,h3`)

**Any advice, how to achieve this optimisation with [cssnano.co](http://cssnano.co) ?** (or another minification gulp task to chain into)

```
body,html{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
h1,h2,h3{
  color:green;
  background-color:#caa;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:500px){
  p{
    background-color:orange;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width:500px){
  div,p{
    background-color:purple;}
}
body,html{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background-color:#aac;
}
h1,h2,h3{
  font-weight:700;
  color:orange;
  text-decoration:underline;
}
html{
  background:orange;
}

h1,h2,h3{
  font-weight:700;
}
p{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#eee;
}
```

(This example is coming from three rather trivial files, merged together. core:false to keep whitespace. Turning it on removes whitespace, but does not fix the mentioned issues. )